# Creating a type with optional fields from variadic arguments in Go

Tags: go, constructor, variadic-functions

I am learning Go right now and would like to initialize a type using variadic arguments without using reflection. Is it possible?

Here an example:

```
type MyType struct {
    field1 string
    field2 string
    ...
    fieldN string
}

func CreateMyType(arguments ...string) *MyType {
    inst := MyType{arguments...}  // does not work, is there any other way???
    return &inst
}
```

**Note** It makes me really sad, that the question is downvoted, where I ask legitimate things and try to learn out of them :(

Comment: No, it is not possible unless you assign it manually or use reflect. It raises the question: why don't use a slice.

Comment: @leafbebop I don't mind to use a slice here, but not reflection. Variadic arguments can be converted to a slice, if I learned it properly.

Comment: I mean, why don't you make all those fieldN thing into a slice field? like `struct { Fields []string }`.

Comment: Looks a bit like you are trying to force something on Go which is not quite right. Leave traditional OOP behind; it will hurt you in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with a little bit of code:

```
func CreateMyType(arguments ...string) *MyType {
    var m MyType
    switch len(arguments) {
    case 3:
        m.field3 = arguments[2]
        fallthrough
    case 2:
        m.field2 = arguments[1]
        fallthrough
    case 1:
        m.field1 = arguments[0]
    }
    return &m
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/ihXtASguOGv)